# admin controller not working in client side Magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.8

I am creating a new module which will record all the data from contact us page.
and all the data information will show in admin panel.

I have following code in my config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Vampi_Contactsform>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </Vampi_Contactsform>
</modules>

<global>
    <models>
        <vampi_contactsform>
            <class>Vampi_Contactsform_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>vampi_contactsform_mysql4</resourceModel>
        </vampi_contactsform>
    </models>

   <resources>
        <vampi_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>Vampi_Contactsform</module>
            </setup>
            <connection>
                <use>core_setup</use>
            </connection>
        </vampi_setup>
        <vampi_write>
            <connection>
                <use>core_write</use>
            </connection>
        </vampi_write>
        <vampi_read>
            <connection>
                <use>core_read</use>
            </connection>
        </vampi_read>
    </resources>

    <blocks>
        <vampi_contactsform>
            <class>Vampi_Contactsform_Block</class>
        </vampi_contactsform>
    </blocks>

    <helpers>
        <vampi_contactsform>
            <class>Vampi_Contactsform_Helper</class>
        </vampi_contactsform>
    </helpers>
</global>

<admin>
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <vampi_contactsform before="Mage_Adminhtml">Vampi_Contactsform_Adminhtml</vampi_contactsform>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>

 <frontend>
    <routers>
        <contactsform>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <vampi_contactsform before="Mage_Contactsform">Vampi_Contactsform</vampi_contactsform>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </contactsform>
    </routers>
</frontend>
```

and my app\code\community\Vampi\Contactsform\controllers\Adminhtml\contactsformController.php contains

```
<?php
class Vampi_Contactsform_Adminhtml_ContactsformController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action{

public function indexAction()
{
    $this->_title($this->__('Sales'))->_title($this->__('Contact Enquiries'));
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->_setActiveMenu('report/contactsform');
    $this->_addContent($this->getLayout()->createBlock('vampi_contactsform/adminhtml_contactsform_list'));
    $this->renderLayout();
}

public function deleteAction() {
    $orderIds = $this->getRequest()->getPost('order_ids', array());
    $countNonCancelOrder = 0;

    foreach ($orderIds as $orderId) {
        $db = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
        $contact_form = Mage::getSingleton("core/resource")->getTableName('contact_form');
        $db->delete($contact_form, "id = $orderId");

        $countNonCancelOrder++;
    }

    if ($countNonCancelOrder) {
            $this->_getSession()->addError($this->__('%s enquiry(s) deleted', $countNonCancelOrder));
    }

    $this->_redirect('*/*/');
}

public function gridAction()
{
    $this->loadLayout();
    $this->getResponse()->setBody(
            $this->getLayout()->createBlock('vampi_contactsform/adminhtml_contactsform_list_grid')->toHtml()
    );
}
}
```

Please help

this is giving 404 Error while opening page from Magento admin panel.

Thanks

Comment: Hi, can you give us the url you are calling? It might be an error in the url. Also, you will need to add acl (authorisations) for you new page by adding an adminhtml.xml file.

Comment: url is http://localhost/magentotest/index.php/admin/contactsform

it is working fine, but in client side it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Thecontroller is generated based on the admin session.
And you cannot share the admin and frontend sessions, that's why when making the call from the frontend 404 not found.

Anyway, it's not a good practice to make calls to frontend actions from the backend.
You should have 2 separate controllers, one for backend and one for frontend.
In order not to duplicate the code, you can put everything inside a method in a helper and just call that method in both controllers.

Comment: I have separate controllers. It is of admin controller. If i am doing anything wrong please guide me.

Comment: What url you are using to access frontend that generate 404 not found?
 because in the frontend url is different from backend

Comment: when I open grid in admin panel it goes to 404 not found page.

Answer (score 0):

Can't give you a ready answer on a platter, but if you follow this [article](http://alanstorm.com/magento_admin_hello_world_revisited) you should be good. Pay attention to the Debugging section on the bottom. It should help you figure out what the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys, that was my silly mistake naming the controller.
I have renamed contactsformController.php  to ContactsformController.php